# Cubic Closed Packed Structure

Tags: mechanical-engineering

In cubic closed pack structure, {111} family is closed pack.The {111} is cubic closed pack in the sense that, in fcc lattice the close packed layer constitute {111} planes. But how do I measure that it stacked along the diagonal <111> direction? For hexagonal closed pack structure, I think {111} is also closed pack as every atom has 6 nearby neighbours atom. But how do it stacked along <111> direction?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have three individual layers with atoms packed in the hexagonal arrangement. Put the first layer down on a table. Call it Layer A. Now add the second layer on top to the first layer. The second layer will fit so that its atoms fill troughs in the first layer. Call this Layer B. Now add the third layer. You will have two choices. You can fill troughs so the third layer has the same positions looking down (perpendicular to) the two existing layers. This gives an A - B - A stacking arrangement. You can alternatively fill troughs that are not filled by Layer A. This gives an A - B - C stacking arrangement.

The A - B - A arrangement is a hexagonal close packed lattice. The A - B - C arrangement is a face centered cube lattice. Detailed pictures of these two cases are typically given in textbooks for materials science and also on line (search for face centered cubic vs hexagonal). The coordination number (number of nearest neighbors) in either 3-D lattice is 12.